# how do you interpret this silhouette result ? (clustering)

Tags: cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, silhouette

Hello I have been assesing clusters in biological genomic data, the issue is that after perfoming a hierarchical clustering, I used silhouette to determine the optimal number of clusters, the silhouette is the following:

[image: silhouette]

AS I understand, if the average silhouette width aproximates to 1, then the number of clusters for that clustering is an optimal one, while if it is close to -1, the elements on the respective clusters may belong to a different one.

In this case the average silhouette width is 0.87 for k =2 but dont know how to interpret the "y" axis.

I used r `fviz_silhouette()` for producing the visualization

Here is the resulting dendogram of the aglomerative hierarchical clustering analysis if needed:

[image: dendogram]